# Hibernate query for searching part of string

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

I'm trying to write a hibernate query to search if table Room contains roomname which contains part of string.The string value is in a variable. I wrote a query to get exact room name from the table.

```
findRoom(String name) {
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Room a WHERE a.roomname=?1");
        query.setParameter(1, name);
        List rooms = query.getResultList();
        return rooms;
         }
```

In sql the query is something like this:

```
mysql_query("
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `column` LIKE '%"name"%' or '%"name"' or '"name"%'
");
```

I want to know the hql query for searching the table that matches my query. I can not use string directly, so the search query has to be veriable based and I need all three types in a query, if it's begin with name, or contains name or ends name.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would do something like that:

```
findRoom(String name) {
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Room a"
                + "WHERE a.roomname LIKE CONCAT('%',?1,'%')");
        query.setParameter(1, name);
        List rooms = query.getResultList();
        return rooms;
         }
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `like` instead of `=`:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Room a WHERE a.roomname like ?1");

query.setParameter(1, "%"+name+"%");
```

Comment: So, %name%' or '%name' or 'name%' is not needed?! @jens

Comment: I need all three types in a query, if it's begin with name, or contains name or ends name.can you help me there?

Comment: I believe that "%"+name+"%" includes the other cases

Comment: @Mahin `%` stands for zero up to n characters. So this `%name%` includes both of the other.